# Why does RabbitMQ keep breaking from a corrupt persister log file?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm running **Celery** in a **Django** app with **RabbitMQ** as the message broker. However, RabbitMQ keeps breaking down like so. First is the error I get from Django. The trace is mostly unimportant, because I know what is causing the error, as you will see.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  ...

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 85, in __init__
    raise socket.error, msg

error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I know that this is due to a corrupt **rabbit_persister.log** file. This is because after I kill all processes tied to RabbitMQ, I run "sudo rabbitmq-server start" to get the following crash:

```
...

starting queue recovery                                               ...done
starting persister                                                    ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
Reason: {{badmatch,{error,{{{badmatch,eof},
                            [{rabbit_persister,internal_load_snapshot,2},
                             {rabbit_persister,init,1},
                             {gen_server,init_it,6},
                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},
                           {child,undefined,rabbit_persister,
                                  {rabbit_persister,start_link,[]},
                                  transient,100,worker,
                                  [rabbit_persister]}}}},
         [{rabbit_sup,start_child,2},
          {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1},
          {rabbit,run_boot_step,1},
          {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
          {rabbit,start,2},
          {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}
Erlang has closed
```

**My current fix:** Every time this happens, I rename the corresponding rabbit_persister.log file to something else (rabbit_persister.log.bak) and am able to restart RabbitMQ with success. But the problem keeps occurring, and I can't tell why. Any ideas?

Also, as a disclaimer, I have no experience with Erlang; I'm only using RabbitMQ because it's the broker favored by Celery.

Thanks in advance, this problem is really annoying me because I keep doing the same fix over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The persister is RabbitMQ's internal message database.  That "log" is presumably like a database log and deleting it will cause you to lose messages.  I guess it's getting corrupted by unclean broker shutdowns, but that's a bit beside the point.

It's interesting that you're getting an error in the `rabbit_persister` module.  The last version of RabbitMQ that has that file is 2.2.0, so I'd strongly advise you to upgrade.  The best version is always the latest, which you can get by using the RabbitMQ [APT repository](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html).  In particular, the persister has seen a fairly large amount of fixes in the versions after 2.2.0, so there's a big chance your problem has already been resolved.

If you still see the problem after upgrading, you should report it on the [RabbitMQ Discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The developers (of both Celery and RabbitMQ) make a point of fixing any problems reported there.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Also, simple question, but is there a command to check the current version of RabbitMQ on the system?

Comment: I mean, aside from just running rabbitmq-server. Like a "rabbitmqctl" version of some sort.

Anyway, turns out I had the latest version on the development server, but a rather old version on the production server! Yikes. I wondered why it never threw that sort of error on the dev server... Thanks so much. Hopefully this answer is helpful to other people too; I found very few results from searching for this problem beforehand.

Comment: No problem.  `rabbitmqctl status` will show you the version at the top.

Answer (score 1):

A. Because you are running an old version of RabbitMQ earlier than 2.7.1
B. Because RabbitMQ doesn't have enough RAM. You need to run RabbitMQ on a server all by itself and give that server enough RAM so that the RAM is 2.5 times the largest possible size of your persisted message log.

You might be able to fix this without any software changes just by adding more RAM and killing other services on the box.

Another approach to this is to build your own RabbitMQ from source and include the toke extension that persists messages using Tokyo Cabinet. Make sure you are using local hard drive and not NFS partitions because Tokyo Cabinet has corruption issues with NFS. And, of course, use version 2.7.1 for this. Depending on your message content, you might also benefit from Tokyo Cabinets compression settings to reduce the read/write activity of persisted messages.